# How to create custom QML Popup in C++?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I know how to create a custom QML Item in C++. To do this I should inherit my class from QQuickPaintedItem. And my class will be a descendant of Item.

But how to create a custom QML Popup in C++? Popup does not inherit Item. It inherits QtObject. Maybe there is some special class for creating custom QML popups like QQuickPaintedItem? Or maybe there is another way to create custom popup in C++?

Comment: see https://github.com/qt/qtquickcontrols2/blob/5.14.1/src/quicktemplates2/qquickpopup.cpp. As you can see, the popup code is part of the private Qt API. On the other hand, popup is a manager, that is, it is not a visual element. The popup handles a QQuickPopupItem that is an item based on QQuickPage (which are the Page items) so I recommend you review the logic for you to implement.

Comment: Why would you need this? Do you need to customize the looks of the popup? If yes, why can't you do this is QML?

Comment: I need to create custom menu. And this menu contains a lot of items so it need a good performance.